# How to create array1 of array2 which value is being replaced with every new query result from DynamoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, initialization, nsuserdefaults

I query to DynamoDB. The result is stored in queryResult array. With every new query to database the value of queryResult array is being changed (replaced). The problem comes when I want to populate my table view controller  (the list of added friends) with all potential results.

I want to create new array that adds every new received result, but unfortunately its value gets overwritten with every new query result. For example, if for the 1st time I want to add "Adam" and next time "Michael" I want an array with values: (Adam, Michael). Now, Michael overwrites Adam. I ask you how can I force an array to store every newly added result - not to overwrite the existing one. Later I would like to loop through that array to populate tables rows. I would appreciate every hint, advice. Thank you very much.

```
- (IBAction)addButton:(UIButton *)sender {
//To store credentials typed by user.
NSString *userName = self.nameTypedTextField.text;
NSString *phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberTextField.text;

//To query for typed credentials.
AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *query = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];
query.hashKeyAttribute = @"userPhoneNumber";
query.hashKeyValues = phoneNumber;

//To receive typed credentials.
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *objectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
[[objectMapper query:[Users class] expression:query] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);

    if (task.exception) NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);

    if (task.result) {
        //I receive query result.
        AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
        NSArray *queryResult = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];
        NSLog(@"Query result: %@", queryResult);

        //I wanted to create array that adds every object that is being stored in queryResult array. It doesnt work - it simply replaces its value with new result.
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObjectsFromArray:queryResult];

        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        //Must be converted to NSData becouse of: Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefualts.
        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:queryResult];
        [userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"User Data"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
     return nil;
    }];
```

}

**EDIT:**
You need to save your very first query result first. arrayByAddingObjectFromArray requires noempty array (previousQueryResult) to add the results from the other array (queryResult). Otherwise you will end up with null statement and you wont be able to stack up the results. That issue occurs only on the very first application launch.

```
if (task.result) {
        //To receive query result.
        AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
        NSArray *queryResult = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];
        NSLog(@"Query result: %@", queryResult);

        //Get the previously stored query results.
        NSData *previousData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"User Data"];
        NSArray *previousQueryResults = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:previousData];

        //If previousQueryResults is empty (due to first applcation launch).
        if ([previousQueryResults count] == 0) {
            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:queryResult];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:data forKey:@"User Data"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        } else {
            //Get the previously stored query results.
            NSData *previousData2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"User Data"];
            NSArray *previousQueryResults2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:previousData2];

            //Add the new query results to what was previously stored.
            NSArray *updatedArray = [previousQueryResults2 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:queryResult];
            NSLog(@"Updated array: %@", updatedArray);

            //Store the combined query results to user defaults.
            NSData *dataUpdated = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:updatedArray];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dataUpdated forKey:@"User Data"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each task completion, you are initializing a new array (which has no items in it) and adding only the new query results in it. This is why it seems like it is "overwriting" the results. When a task finishes, you should get the previous results from user defaults and add the new query results to that. I have updated your code to show how that can be done:

```
if (task.result) {
    //I receive query result.
    AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
    NSArray *queryResult = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];
    NSLog(@"Query result: %@", queryResult);

    // Get the previously stored query results
    NSData *previousData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"User Data"];
    NSArray *previousQueryResults = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:previousData];

    // Add the new query results to what was previously stored
    NSArray *array = [previousQueryResults arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:queryResults];

    // Store the combined query results to user defaults
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"User Data"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```